# Is there a better way to check selected item in Jquery ui selectable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image display div, the user can delete selected images. This code works fine but everything, where I marked, repeats a certain amount of times. I have tried using  `$(".ui-selected").each()` in order to do the statement just till the selected items get removed, but this didn't work.

```
$("#containimage").bind("mousedown", function(e) {//this function give the ability to toggle selection
    e.metaKey = true;
}).selectable({
    selected: function() {

        $("#containimage img").each(function() {//check all the images inside the container
            if ($(this).hasClass("ui-selected")) {//check if it is selected

                $("#deleteselection").on("click", function() {//check when delete button is pressed

                    $(".ui-selected").each(function() {//apply for only selected
                        var imagepath = $(this).attr("src");

/*==============================everything from here==============================*/
                        console.log(imagepath);

//the $.get below is for passing the image path to the php file in order to delete via unlink
// i have no problem with the numerous repetition of the code but i know that this can be avoided for a better performance
                        $.get("delete_file.php", {
                            filepath: imagepath
                        }).done(function(data) {
                            console.log(data);
                            if (data == "file removed") {
                                $('.ui-selected').remove();
                            } else {}
                        });
/*==============================to here==============================*/
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I have also tried making a timeout like this, nothing worked

```
 setTimeout(() => {
                        $(".ui-selected").each(function() {
                            var imagepath = $(this).attr("src");
                            console.log(imagepath);
                            $.get("delete_file.php", {
                                filepath: imagepath
                            }).done(function(data) {
                                console.log(data);
                                if (data == "file removed") {
                                    $('.ui-selected').remove();
                                } else {}
                            });
                        });
                    }, 500);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try turning off the event before putting it

```js
new Uint8Array(8).forEach(_ => {

    $("#deleteselection").on("click", function() {
        console.log('Hi, how are you ?');
    });
    
})

new Uint8Array(8).forEach(_ => {

    $("#withoff").off(); // <-- off events
    $("#withoff").on("click", function() {
        console.log('how are you ? only one');
    });
    
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="deleteselection">without off</button>
<button id="withoff">with off</button>
```

Comment: The code is working fine it is deleting only the selected image. None the less when i try deleting only one image the code runs only one time, when i try deleting another image after i deleted the first one, the code runs twice, and sometimes after the second removal the code runs 12 or 30 times. i just want to improve the code.